# Circles around a center point in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

So I'm trying to create a table map responsively with React, circles are generated by kanva for each seat added in JSON.

What happens is that I'm managing to separate the seats into columns, but I can't make these seats stay around the central circle (the table), could someone help me just how to make the circles stay around the central circle?

Here's the code i'm using to generate and align the seats with the table.

```
export const SEAT_SIZE = 10;
export const SEATS_DISTANCE = 15;
export const SUBSECTION_PADDING = 30;

export const SECTIONS_MARGIN = 10;
export const SECTION_TOP_PADDING = 40;
export const SECTION_TITLE_PADDING = 5;

export const X_TABLE = 45;
export const Y_TABLE = 36.8;
export const RADIUS_TABLE = SEAT_SIZE * 1.2;
```

This is the reference for creating tables and seats dynamically.

```
const Seat = props => {
  const isBooked = props.data.status === "booked";

  return (
    <Circle
      x={props.x}
      y={props.y}
      radius={SEAT_SIZE / 2}
      fill={getColor(isBooked, props.isSelected)}
      strokeWidth={1}
      onMouseEnter={e => {
        e.target._clearCache();
        props.onHover(props.data.name, e.target.getAbsolutePosition());
        const container = e.target.getStage().container();
        if (isBooked) {
          container.style.cursor = "not-allowed";
        } else {
          container.style.cursor = "pointer";
        }
      }}
      onMouseLeave={e => {
        props.onHover(null);
        const container = e.target.getStage().container();
        container.style.cursor = "";
      }}
      onClick={e => {
        if (isBooked) {
          return;
        }
        if (props.isSelected) {
          props.onDeselect(props.data.name);
        } else {
          props.onSelect(props.data.name);
        }
      }}
      onTap={e => {
        if (isBooked) {
          return;
        }
        if (props.isSelected) {
          props.onDeselect(props.data.name);
        } else {
          props.onSelect(props.data.name);
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

The findX and findY functions are the functions I'm using to try to align the seats around the table, I'm doing **everything** related to that in them

```
  function findX(rowIndex, seatIndex) {
    let x = 25.8;
    let isPair = seatIndex % 2  == 0 ? true : false;

    if (!isPair) {
      x += 40;
    }
    return x; 
  }

  function findY(rowIndex, seatIndex) {
    let y = seatIndex > 4 ? + 5 : 25;
    y += 15 * (rowIndex + 1);
    return y;
  }
```

This code is what creates the seats dynamically, using the references

```
      {Object.keys(data.map_qtd_fileiras).map((rowKey, rowIndex) => {
        const row = data.map_qtd_fileiras[rowKey];
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={rowKey}>
            {row.map((seat, seatIndex) => {
              return (
                <Group key={'group-' + seat.name}>
                  <Table
                  radius={SEAT_SIZE * 1.2}
                  key={'table-' + seat.name}
                  data={seat}
                  mb={8}
                  onHover={onHoverSeat}
                  onSelect={onSelectSeat}
                  onDeselect={onDeselectSeat}
                  isSelected={selectedSeatsIds.indexOf(seat.name) >= 0}
              />
                  
                  <Seat
                    key={seat.name}
                    x={seatIndex > 4
                      ? findY(rowIndex, seatIndex)
                      : findX(rowIndex, seatIndex)}
                    y={seatIndex > 4
                      ? findX(rowIndex, seatIndex)
                      : findY(rowIndex, seatIndex)}
                    data={seat}
                    onHover={onHoverSeat}
                    onSelect={onSelectSeat}
                    onDeselect={onDeselectSeat}
                    isSelected={selectedSeatsIds.indexOf(seat.name) >= 0}
                  />
                </Group>
              );
            })}
```

And this is the reference JSON:

```
{
  "seats": {
    "sections": [
      {
        "event_id": "2",
        "name": "\u00c1REA VIP",
        "color": null,
        "subsections": [
          {
            "id": "5",
            "section_id": 1,
            "name": "VIP 5",
            "map_qtd_fileiras": {
              "1": [
                {
                  "name": "D1",
                  "status": "free"
                },
                {
                  "name": "D1",
                  "status": "free"
                }
              ],
              "2": [
                {
                  "name": "D1",
                  "status": "free"
                },
                {
                  "name": "D1",
                  "status": "free"
                }
              ],
              "3": [
                {
                  "name": "D1",
                  "status": "free"
                },
                {
                  "name": "D1",
                  "status": "free"
                }
              ], 
              "4": [
                {
                  "name": "D1",
                  "status": "free"
                },
                {
                  "name": "D1",
                  "status": "free"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And my return is exactly this:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPOFG.png)

But I need a return similar to this:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00Pr2.png)